# Perl Script for logging into a website and displaying the next page

Tags: perl, authentication, web, www-mechanize

I am writing a Perl script to log into a website and display the next page after login. Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use WWW::Mechanize;
use HTTP::Cookies;
my $m=WWW::Mechanize->new();

# Debug tricks
$m->default_header('Accept-Encoding' => scalar HTTP::Message::decodable());
$m->add_handler("request_send",  sub { shift->dump; return });
$m->add_handler("response_done", sub { shift->dump; return });

my $outfile="out.htm";
$m->cookie_jar(HTTP::Cookies->new());
$url = '<url>';
$m->get($url);

$m->field(Email=>"abc");
$m->field(Passwd=>"def");

$m->click();

my $output_page= $m->content();
open(OUTFILE, ">$outfile");
print OUTFILE "$output_page";
close(OUTFILE);

sub open_default_browser{

    $platform=$^O;

    print "$platform";

    $url=shift;

    $cmd="start $url";

    if(defined $cmd) {
        system($cmd);
    }
    else {
        die "Can't locate default browser";
    }
}

open_default_browser($outfile);
```

But when I run the code all I get is a web page with the same form from the URL.How can I login and display the next page. Is there something I need to change in the code?

Comment: You use debug, have you read the debug output ? Show us

Comment: That code looks like it should work, assuming 1) the website doesn't require JavaScript and 2) the `name` attributes of the fields in the first form in the page are `Email` and `Passwd` and 3) those are the only two fields that need to be set and 4) you're using the correct email and password. Unfortunately, without knowing the exact URL you're connecting to, we probably can't be of much help. Also, that script doesn't do much error checking; you should read the [docs](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Mechanize) for `WWW::Mechanize` and check that the initial `GET` request succeeds, for example.

Comment: @sputnick I am new to perl and hence I read it somewhere.But while running the code nothing comes up on command line. Is there any way to debug the code?

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot I read many docs on WWW::Mechanize. Many places they follow same kind of code to log into a website. I am not sure how to know if we are successful in logging in and how to display the next page after logging in.

Comment: Added `Debug tricks` in your post, run the script and see. `use LWP::Debug qw(+);` is deprecated. Code indented too, it's better when asking others help

Comment: @user227668, it doesn't matter what many sites do if this site uses JavaScript for some key aspect of logging in. If it does some key thing on page load or form submission, you'll have to look through the JavaScript to find what it's doing--most likely what it's adding to the post parameters.

Comment: @Axeman The site I am logging in has javascript in the source code of its login page.What to do if a site uses javascript? Will WWW::Mechanize wont work in such a case. Is there a way out?

Comment: [`WWW::Mechanize` doesn't support JavaScript](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Mechanize::FAQ#JavaScript). If you need something that supports it, try something like [`WWW::Mechanize::Firefox`](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Mechanize::Firefox) or [`WWW::Mechanize::PhantomJS`](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Mechanize::PhantomJS). Before just blindly switching modules, though, you should make sure that JS is really required to login. Use your browser's developer tools to inspect a request when you log in normally via the browser to see what is actually happening.

Comment: On changing the module, will the code be the same or it will differ?I saw the code, there were some places where JS was used. As i dont know much about JS how do we know if it is being used in logon.?

Comment: @user227668 Fire up firefox, open `about:config`, then type `javascript.enable`, double-click on the link to disable it, and refresh the wanted page. If the stuff you want aren't there, then no cigar... Got it ?

Answer (score 0):

Also: How many buttons are on the page?  If there is more than one, then you need to provide the name of the button to be clicked:

```
$m->click( "button name" );
```

Comment: only one button so I guess only $m->click() will do the work.